# Webpack Font Awesome fonts getting wrong path

Tags: javascript, webpack, font-awesome

When I run `npm run production` it builds my JS and CSS (from SASS) and puts it in my drupal themes directory. The paths for the fonts are incorrect in my `fontawesome.css`.

The paths should look like 
`../fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webwebfa-brands-400.woff?5dd043615247f4082a329ccccaacca7b`

or

`/themes/<theme-name>/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webwebfa-brands-400.woff?5dd043615247f4082a329ccccaacca7b`

but they are being generated like `/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-webwebfa-brands-400.woff?5dd043615247f4082a329ccccaacca7b`

I have tried to add in a webpack.config.js file to get this working however I have not had much luck with this and I am really unsure what I'm doing. I never really did get this working correctly but I have included my code below.

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  src: './web/themes/<theme-name>/src/',
  dist: './web/themes/<theme-name>/'
};

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: config.src + 'js/app.js' ,
    sass: config.src + 'sass/app.scss'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, config.dist)
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)(\?\S*)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: config.dist + 'fonts/',
            publicPath: '/themes/<theme-name>/fonts/'
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.